# Change numa group in running process via PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I would like to change numa group in running process via PS

all the time is take group 1 :( and cpu work 50%

this - I can do by hand but I don`t know how via PS

**my problem is that I have processes that always get assigned to the same group, resulting in 50% of the cpu**

[image]

Mathias when I add 2 I get this (in the powershell instruction the bitmask controlls number of cpus to in a processor group only - so if the process get's assigned to a group 0, the instruction only changes the number of cpus in this group)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not what I call an answer actually (I am not a C++ dev), however, here is a part of the way to probably achieve this :

```
$MethodDefinition = @'
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool SetThreadGroupAffinity(......);
'@
$Kernel32 = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $MethodDefinition -Name "Kernel32" -PassThru

#Retrieve the Thread handle first
#Call by $Kernel32::SetThreadGroupAffinity(......)
```

[MS docs SetThreadGroupAffinity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processtopologyapi/nf-processtopologyapi-setthreadgroupaffinity),
[MS docs GoupAfffinity Structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-group_affinity)

May be this one be useful too [MS docs SetThreadAffinityMask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadaffinitymask)

Answer (score 2):

You need to [set the `ProcessorAffinity` property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44860951/712649) on the corresponding process:

```bsh
Get-Process vmmem |ForEach-Object {
  $_.ProcessorAffinity = [IntPtr]::new([long]-1) # -1 corresponds to all 64 bits set
}
```

Comment: it work only in one group, we have 72 cores (two processors)

Comment: (36 cores / 72 vcpus) (2 numa nodes)

Comment: @RafałDeveloper so when you set the `ProcessorAffinity` like in my example above, task manager still only shows half of the CPU's checked? Try setting it to `2` instead of `-1` (I can't remember if it affects groups as a whole and I don't have a NUMA die to test)

Comment: all cpus (exactly 35) checked in group 1 and zero cpus in group 0

Comment: Alright, that means each bit controls a group, so setting it to `3` should allow execution on both groups

Comment: @RafałDeveloper Well, you're in a better position to validate the right pattern than I am, so I would suggest trying different values until you get the right result (sorry I can't be of more help)

Comment: in the powershell instruction the bitmask controlls number of cpus to in a processor group only - so if the process get's assigned to a group 0, the instruction only changes the number of cpus in this group.